# distinct not working with other columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use distinct in my query

```
select distinct tvpAuditevent.TESTSEQUENCEID
from tvpAuditevent
where tvpAuditevent.Name = 'WorkstepCompleted';
```

it works fine. and give me only 100 Results

But now if I add other columns like this

```
select distinct tvpAuditevent.TESTSEQUENCEID, tvpAuditevent.USERNAME
from  tvpAuditevent
where tvpAuditevent.Name = 'WorkstepCompleted';
```

it gives me around 200 results, which is wrong. 
I need to only those 100 results but need other columns as well other than testsequenceId.

Please let me know if there is a way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: This means that you have different values of `username` per `testsequenceid`. Which `username` should be displayed in that case?

Comment: your point is valid , i didnt notice , let me see , thanks

Answer (score 4):

As explained in another answer, the `distinct` keyword applies to all the columns in the `select` statement.  You cannot limit it to just one column.

Instead, you can use `group by` along with an aggregation function.  For instance, the following returns the minimum value from the second column:

```
select ae.TESTSEQUENCEID, min(ae.USERNAME)
from  tvpAuditevent ae
where ae.Name = 'WorkstepCompleted'
group by ae.TESTSEQUENCEID;
```

In fact, the `distinct` keyword in a `select` is just a notational convenience.  The following:

```
select distinct col1, col2, . . ., coln
from table t
```

does the same thing as:

```
select col1, col2, . . . coln
from table t
group by col1, col2, . . . coln
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `DISTINCT` will simply remove duplicate results from the result set. It cannot be applied to a single column when you are selecting multiple columns.

What you want exactly is not clear. Let's say we have the following data, where the first value is the column you want to be distinct, and the other the column you want to display as "extra data".

```
A,B
A,C
```

What should the result be? `A,B` or `A,C`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT S.TESTSEQUENCEID,
 AE.tvpAuditevent.USERNAME     
FROM tvpAuditevent AE
JOIN     (select distinct tvpAuditevent.TESTSEQUENCEID 
 from tvpAuditevent where tvpAuditevent.Name = 'WorkstepCompleted' ) S
 ON S.TESTSEQUENCEID = AE.TESTSEQUENCEID
where AE.tvpAuditevent.Name = 'WorkstepCompleted'
```

Comment: A single query with no explanation. Yet I'm convinced it's not even clear from OP's question what he wants to achieve.

Comment: this query give L SQL Error: ORA-00904: "S"."TESTSEQUENCEID": invalid identifier

Comment: @junaidp . . . That's because the syntax is incorrect for Oracle.  But, even if the syntax worked (by changing `AS S` to just `S`, the query wouldn't do what you wanted anyway.

Comment: I changed the `AS` but yes you are right, however the OP doesn't really make sense. lol